# What factors cause or prevent "generational loss" when JPEGs are recompressed multiple times?

Tags: jpeg, image-compression

For years, I've believed that *recompressing JPEG files multiple times* would gradually degrade its quality until they are an unrecognizable mess, the way making photocopies of photocopies does. This intuitively makes sense because JPEG is a lossy format. There are also other Q&As that claim this is so:

- [What image quality is lost when re-saving a JPEG image in MS Paint?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34878/75526)
- [Does simply opening and closing a JPEG file decrease image quality?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56304/75526)

However, I've also read that recompressing JPEGs at the same quality level will *not* degrade the image quality. This runs counter to the gradual degradation that is described elsewhere.

**What *technically* happens when a JPEG is recompressed?** What is being lost and how? Will the image *really* transform into the snowy mess that used to appear on television? What about those videos showing images that fall apart after being recompressed multiple times?

*(Please don't merely handwave and appeal to the general concept of lossiness.)*

(This question, and the answers it has attracted so far, focus on the *technical factors* (specific settings and image manipulations) that cause or prevent image degradation when a JPEG file is recompressed *multiple* times.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What image quality is lost when re-saving a JPEG image in MS Paint?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34878/what-image-quality-is-lost-when-re-saving-a-jpeg-image-in-ms-paint)

Comment: On the other hand: [Does simply opening and closing a JPEG file decrease image quality?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56304/15871)

Comment: [**Relevant**](https://github.com/google/knusperli).

Comment: If you re-compress but the setting is at 100% then in theory you lose nothing. If you re-compress the same file at 80% several times then you do keep losing significant amounts of data and will start to see artifacts. In practice this is most prevalent on image sharing sites where images get taken and re-uploaded to other sites. If the compression ratio metadata is missing or is ignored then compression gets applied and re-applied.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Some (small) amount of image data is lost by *rounding error* at quality 100. Recompressing at the *same setting* (such as 80) does **not** result in *progressive* data loss. That is the "common knowledge" this Q&A is intended to address.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The values like "100" and "80" (or "10, 11, 12" in Photoshop) are arbitrary — 100% is not lossless.

Comment: Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1683/

Comment: @xiota True. But many wire services—and photo pros—follow a workflow that goes something like: RAW to TIFF and then to a JPEG at 100%. For most uses, the initial conversion to a JPEG is rock solid. Going past that? Yeah, rounding errors. But make sure the image is read-only or just be very careful and you are good.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really a (complex) problem relating to computer algorithm performance and the (extreme) details of the JPEG standard and implementations.

Answer (score 36):

Almost all image quality losses occur the first time an image is compressed as JPEG. Regardless of how many times a JPEG is recompressed *with the same settings*, **generational losses are limited to rounding error.**

- MCU boundaries remain are intact (8x8 blocks).
- Chroma subsampling is disabled.
- Constant DQT (same quality setting).

However, **rounding errors may be large** for each iteration that the above criteria are not met, and **it is prudent to keep backups of all original files.**

---

#### [The JPEG compression algorithm](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-compression.html)

1. Convert colorspace. If desired, downsample color information (chroma subsampling) **(Lossy)**. If not downsampled, loss of information is the result of **rounding error**.
2. Segmentation. Divide each channel into 8x8 blocks (MCU = Minimal Coding Unit). **(Lossless)**

   *Note: If chroma subsampling is enabled, MCUs may effectively be 16x8, 8x16, or 16x16, in terms of the original image. However, the MCUs are still all 8x8 blocks.*
3. Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT) on each MCU. Loss of information is the result of **rounding error**.
4. **Quantization.** The value in each cell of the MCU is divided by a number specified in a quantization table (DQT). Values are rounded down, many of which will become zero. **This is the primary lossy portion of the algorithm.**
5. Zig-Zag Scan. Rearrange values in each MCU into a sequence of numbers following a zig-zag pattern. The zeros that occurred during quantization will be grouped together. **(Lossless)**
6. DPCM = Differential Pulse Code Modulation. Convert the number sequences into a form that is easier to compress. **(Lossless)**
7. RLE = Run Length Encoding. Consecutive zeros are compressed. **(Lossless)**
8. Entropy/Huffman Coding. **(Lossless)**

#### Recompressing JPEGs

Note that **downsampling the color channels and quantization are the only intentionally lossy steps**. Setting aside rounding error for now, all other steps are lossless. Once quantization has occurred, reversing and repeating the step gives identical results. In other words, **re-quantization (with the same DQT) is lossless**.

In principle, it is possible to create a resampling algorithm that is lossless after the first pass. However, with the implementation in ImageMagick, colors may shift drastically before steady state is reached, as seen in ths' image.

Given optimal conditions, recompressing a JPEG with the same quality settings would result in the exact same JPEG. In other words, **recompressing JPEGs is *potentially* lossless**. In practice, recompressing JPEGs is not lossless, but subject to, and limited by, rounding error. Although **rounding errors often eventually converge to zero**, so that the exact same image is re-created, **chroma subsampling may result in significant color changes.**

#### Demonstration (same quality setting)

I wrote the following `bash` script, which uses ImageMagick to repeatedly recompress a JPEG file at a given quality setting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
n=10001; q1=90
convert original.png -sampling-factor 4:4:4 -quality ${q1} ${n}.jpg

while true ; do
   q2=${q1}            # for variants, such as adding randomness
   convert ${n}.jpg -quality ${q2} $((n+1)).jpg
   #\rm $((n-5)).jpg   # uncomment to avoid running out of space
   n=$((n+1))

   echo -n "$q2  "
   md5sum ${n}.jpg
done
```

After letting it run for a few hundred iterations, I ran `md5sum` on the results:

```
d9c0d55ee5c8b5408f7e50f8ebc1010e  original.jpg

880db8f146db87d293def674c6845007  10316.jpg
880db8f146db87d293def674c6845007  10317.jpg
880db8f146db87d293def674c6845007  10318.jpg
880db8f146db87d293def674c6845007  10319.jpg
880db8f146db87d293def674c6845007  10320.jpg
```

We can see that, indeed, the rounding error has converged to zero, and **the exact same image is being reproduced, over and over**.

I have repeated this multiple times with different images and quality settings. Usually, steady state is reached, and the *exact* same image is reproduced over and over.

#### What about [@mattdm's results](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/99608/75526)?

I have attempted to replicate mattdm's results using Imagemagick on Ubuntu 18.04. The original was a raw conversion to TIFF in Rawtherapee, but it seems to be no longer available. In its place, I took the enlarged version and reduced it to its original size (256x256).  Then I repeatedly recompressed at 75 until I got convergence. Here is the result (original, 1, n, difference):

[image: attempt to replicate mattdm]

My results are different. Without the true original, the reason for the difference is impossible to determine.

#### What about [@ths's montage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtob6.jpg)?

I recompressed the image from the upper left corner of the montage until convergence at 90. This is the result (original, 1, n, difference):

[image: attempt to replicate ths-montage]

**After enabling chroma subsampling, the colors do change** by the time steady state is reached.

[image: ths-color-shift]

#### Changing among a small number of settings

By modifying the variable `q2`, the quality setting can be limited to a set of evenly distributed values.

```
q2=$(( (RANDOM % 3)*5  + 70 ))
```

**For a *small number of setting choices,* equilibrium may eventually reached**, which is seen when md5 values begin recurring. It seems the larger the set, the longer it takes, and the worse the image becomes, before equilibrium can be reached.

What seems to happen at equilibrium is the DCT coefficient prior to quantization has to be divisible all (or most) of the quantum values. For example, if switching between two DQTs where DCT coefficient is divided alternately by 3 and 5, equilibrium will be reached when the DCT coefficient is divisible by 15. This explains why the drop in quality is much greater than the difference between the original settings.

#### Changing among a larger number of settings

Eeyore is not happy when `q2` is changed like so:

```
q2=$(( (RANDOM % 9)  + 90 ))
```

To make a video, use `ffmpeg`:

```
rename 's@1@@' 1*.jpg
ffmpeg -r 30 -i %04d.jpg -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Watching [the first 9999 iterations](https://youtu.be/ft6hr7zjPnA) is almost like watching water boil. Might want to double playback speed. Here is Eeyore after 11999 iterations:

[image: 11999 iterations, random DQT]

#### What if MCU boundaries change?

If changes occur a limited number of times, repeatedly recompressing is likely to reach steady state. If changes occur at each iteration, the image will probably degrade in a manner similar to when DQT changes.

- This is what happens in [videos that rotate](https://youtu.be/TGJ9aKq-Wr0) an image with dimensions that are not divisible by 8.

#### What about editing?

The effect of recompressing after editing depends on the particular edit performed. For instance, saving at the same quality setting after reducing JPEG artifacts would reintroduce the same artifacts. However, applying a localized change, such as a healing brush, would not affect areas that were not touched.

The greatest drop in image quality occurs the first time the file is compressed at a given quality setting. Subsequently recompressing with the same setting should not introduce any change greater than rounding error. So I would expect edit-resave cycles at a given quality setting to look like any other image saved with the same quality setting (as long as MCU boundaries stay intact and **chroma subsampling is disabled**).

#### What about those videos?

- Faulty JPEG implementation? ([Re-saving 500 times with Photoshop at 10/12.](https://youtu.be/aOMUIDvKulw))
- Changing quality settings. (Most videos.)
- Disrupting MCU boundaries. (Cropping or [Rotating](https://youtu.be/TGJ9aKq-Wr0))
- Other maneuvers that reduce image quality or interfere with the JPEG algorithm?

#### Can I over-write my originals with recompressed JPEGs?

**It is prudent to keep backups of all original files,** but if you accidentally overwrite one, the damage is likely limited. It would also be fine to work in JPEG **with chroma subsampling disabled.**

JPEG cannot be used for images that use more than 8 bits per color.

Comment: the picture is quite different with load-*edit*-save loops, though. in this case, repeated quantization will cause degradation.

Comment: Sure, it converges — but only after getting a lot worse.

Comment: i just made a test with the same script as in the answer. here is a montage of every 20th image up tp 100:https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtob6.jpg that is significant.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of the videos. (Well, the top videos I found are straightforward about explaining themselves, actually.)

Comment: FWIW, my original is a portion of the frame of an image from a 2012 DSLR converted in Rawtherapee (and originally exported as TIFF).

Comment: ImageMagick would have been whatever was in Fedora at that time; probably 6.7.8.9.

Comment: strange. i can't reproduce it now either. i'm actually on win, so i replicated the script in batch, but i'm at a loss what could have caused the effect.

Comment: ok. try it with this one:https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Z3B.jpg all i  did originally was to scale my source image and save it with 100% from irfanview. that seems to make the difference.

Comment: Please see my answer w.r.t. what the videos are doing. I haven't found any (at least, not in five minutes of searching) that purport to be saving repeatedly with the same quality settings — all are upfront about either making some change to the image or using random compression settings for each frame.

Comment: ah. found the problem with my image. if you have chroma subsampling turned on, that leads to progressive degradation.

Comment: Found that too. So enabling chroma subsampling significantly alters the color in the image before steady state is reached.

Comment: OOH. That's a nice finding. Cool!

Comment: Repeated loads and saves using the exact same parameters would likely not introduce unbounded quality loss, since most input files could be loaded and re-saved without introducing additional rounding error, and files that would be affected by rounding errors would occur would likely be transformed into files that wouldn't.  On the other hand, repeated loading/save cycles that alternate between compression parameters that are similar but not identical could result in rounding errors on every cycle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that _most_ or all cameras save JPEG files with chroma subsampling (usually 4:2:2), even in high quality modes. That's pretty relevant to practical application of this answer — that plus the fact that the videos are not saving with the same parameters make me really wish you didn't start what is a generally a good answer with "it is a myth".

Comment: I think the "application dependent" aspect of this is very important. I always assume that people get lossless out of their device because that is the right way to do things but it's only possible to do so in a professional or industrial workflow. In a camera phone the native format is JPG and then a series of apps may all modify and resave the file without even exposing format control, much less type and degree of compression. Perhaps that is a separate question.

Comment: @PhotoScientist In the camera phone case, lots of loss should be assumed, especially when the image comes in at something like 1024x768.

Comment: That is part of why I wonder. Many of the sins of the camera phone are forgiven because the images we view are so tiny in comparison to the spatial resolution of the sensor. A severely artifacted 14mp image will look nearly perfect if viewed on a screen that is only 1400 pixels wide. I worry about the legacy of these images. There will be no "zooming in for details" as could be done with high res raws or film before that. Maybe this is just my personal soap box though.

Comment: @PhotoScientist You can examine the DQT of JPEG files from different sources with `exiftool -v5 image.jpg | grep -v RST`

Comment: Was the left picture the image after using the lowest quality (once) from among the range chosen?  If not, it might be helpful to show what that would look like, to indicate how much noise is from generational loss, versus simply being a result of the poorest quality setting.

Comment: Except for Eeyore, left picture is after a single compression step b/c the intent is to compare losses from repeated re-compression. I will update images to include original as well.

Comment: I'd been wondering about the Eeyore one in particular.  That rightmost picture is pretty bad, and I don't think even the lowest quality setting you use would introduce artifacts that are anywhere close to that. It would also be nice to see how the convergence point when using ten values 90-99 compares with using five values 75-95 restricted to multiples of five.

Comment: Updated with video of Eeyore...

Comment: For a kind-of worst-case scenario, suppose quant values are 10 primes... 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31... The DCT coefficient would have to be divisible by 100280245065 for equilibrium to be reached. Using 32-bit representations, there is no non-zero value for which this can occur. The image would become unrecognizable.

Answer (score 21):

**Recompression loss is real, especially when working with higher levels of JPEG compression.**

In theory, if you re-save a JPEG files with the exact same parameters *and* have aligned your crop to 8×8 blocks, the degradation *should* be minimal. However, if you're using a high level of compression, you will see further loss, because the *artifacts* introduced by the initial compression are permanent changes to the image and will get recompressed too, causing more artifacts.

If you re-save with a low level of compression (high quality, like "100" in Gimp or 11 or 12 in Photoshop), any newly added artifacts will be hard to notice. It won't make the image any *better*, but not significantly worse. However, it *will* introduce changes across the whole image.

As a quick test, I used ImageMagick to recompress a JPEG image over and over at 75%. The samples below are uploaded as PNG files to avoid yet further recompression, and were doubled in size when I converted to PNG to make the effect more obvious. (The originals used in the test were not doubled.) It turns out that after eight resamplings, the effect converged on a perfectly stable result, where recompressing again results in a bit-for-bit identical file.

Here's the uncompressed original:

[image: original, no jpeg compression]

Here's the result of going to 75% JPEG:

[image: first jpeg]

And here's that resaved:

[image: second pass]

**That single second save causes a large amount of additional degradation!**

And here's the final converged image (8th pass):

[image: converged jpeg]

Again, colors are definitely *even more* off, including some false color patterns, and the blocky artifacts jump out more. The algorithm converges, but to a significantly degraded version. **So, don't do that.**

But here's the same thing with a 99% quality level, after 9 passes (the point where it converges so further passes are identical):

[image: 99% 9 times]

Here, the difference barely registers. (I mean that literally; compare them pixel by pixel to the non-compressed version and the deviation is just very slight random noise.) So, what if I go back to that first 75% image and then resave at 99%? Well, this, (after just once):

[image: 75% once and then 99% once]

Saving at high quality is definitely *visibly* better than resaving with the same parameters, kind of to my surprise. But, there's obvious *new* degradation around the pink trimming and the eyes. With the recycled version of the same settings, the JPEG artifacts are being exaggerated with each recompression. With the low resolution and low quality I've chosen, that turns out to be worse than recompressing everything differently.

On those videos: I found [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjhomJ04S18) as a top Google hit. Note that it says in the description:

> This is what happens if you re-encode a JPEG image many times, *at random high quality settings* (85 or above).

*Emphasis added* — this explains why there isn't any convergence, because instead of saving with the same settings, or saving at super high quality, *random settings are used each time*.

The [second video I found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQjtVzsYKWY) says:

> A JPEG image was copied and rotated a full revolution for each image. [...] (596 "rotate clockwise" actions)

So, again, something was done to keep the errors accumulating.

In any case, **for practical photo editing**, it's worth mentioning that **saving 75% *one time* is much worse than resaving at 99% a *million* times**. In my example case, the artifacts at 75% are so obvious that the further degradation is like dumping water in the ocean. If you save at a high enough level that these artifacts are not really visible, saving again with the original settings is a good strategy. Of course, if you can stick to always working from uncompressed originals, you're better off.

If for some reason you have to (or strongly prefer to) just work with JPEG, **set your camera to save in the highest quality possible**, even if you don't notice the difference in the initial files. See [Is it worth using Pentax's Premium JPEG quality setting?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21690/is-it-worth-using-pentaxs-premium-jpeg-quality-setting/21691#21691) for more on that — not necessarily really Pentax specific.

Comment: (1) You're saving at 75%. At that setting, loss of image quality is expected. (2) That image was selected and altered to exaggerate JPEG compression artifacts. (3) The image converges after 8 recompression rounds, after which there will be no further reduction in image quality. (4) A video of that image showing "generation loss" would have a whole lot of nothing happening after the first 1/4 second.

Comment: (1)Yes. (2) "Selected" as a typical photo where one might care about this kind of thing. "Altered" only to zoom in. Note that this is only for *display* here — I didn't double the size of the image I was working with. (3) Yes, but in practice for editing, it's the first few rounds you might care about. (4) That's true, but it doesn't imply that converging to the worst case and staying there is useful in any way.

Comment: To replicate, take the first image and resize to 256×256 without any resampling or interpolation.

Comment: I can't *see* much of a difference between the images you show. But if I take the difference of a singly-recompressed and a mutliply-recompressed image and amplify it to make it visible, I get this (much more convincing) result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/57uaY.png  (see my deleted answer on what was done exactly)  It's more convincing because people don't have to keep staring at the image to detect minute differences.

Comment: The differences are pretty small. If you have a large LCD screen, the different "gamma" that results from slightly different viewing angles can make artifacts appear more prominent.

Comment: The differences may be small in the absolutes, but they're pretty terrible in terms of what they do to color and detail, especially around the kids' eyes and in the skin tones. I think that's more useful than the abstract display of different blocks, because from that it's easy to conclude that the overall impact is just a small fraction of the frame. I'll look at inserting some more explanation.

Comment: The randomly changing DQT, rotations, and other image manipulations between recompression cycles explains what happens in the videos. However, I am unable to replicate your results with the images for 75->75. For 75->99, additional loss of image quality is expected because of the DQT change.

Comment: @xiota Hmmm, you say: _I took the enlarged original; ran it through a filter to remove pre-existing JPEG artifacts; reduced its size by 50% because that was the original size; and applied some mild sharpening._ The original shouldn't have any JPEG artifacts, as it was TIFF->PNG. And I don't think sharpening should have any big effect on the experiment, but if you resize with no interpolation you should get back the exact original without any need to.

Comment: I tried with/without the additional filters/steps. When I overlay the images on top of each other to see the differences, I just see black.  Without the true original image, it's impossible to say what happened when you originally performed the experiment. Maybe you should repeat the process with new images and show them without enlargement. It won't look as impressive, but it'll be more accurate and reproducible.

Comment: (And it will be easier to scroll up and down this page.)

Comment: recreated images without filters...

Comment: Hmmm. That's interesting! I'll look into it when I get a chance. Always possible I did something wrong and accidentally exacerbated the degradation.

Answer (score 5):

Recompression does have a measurable effect on image quality and that effect is much more pronounced when changing compression rates.

As a quick check here as some [SSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) values for operations performed on a test image containing a combination of line features and continuous features. I selected JPG95 because that is what I was taught to use at Ad-photo school and JPG83 because that is common among digital content providers.

- Save Tiff image as JPG95 - .9989
- Save Tiff image as JPG83 - .9929
- Resave JPG95 image as JPG95 10 times - .9998
- Resave JPG83 image as JPG83 10 times - .9993
- Resave JPG95 as JPG83 then resave as JPG95 - .9929
- Resave JPG95 as JPG83 then JP83 to JP92 then JPG92 to JPG86 - .9914

So the amount of structural similarity lost to resaving at the same compression 10 times is 1/10th of that lost as saving it at the quality from tiff. However, the quality loss from changing the JPG compression even once is the same as the quality lost to saving that image from Tiff to JPG.

I'll run this test a few more ways and update.

**Methodology**:
In ImageJ:

1. Convert Tiff RGB to grayscale 8-bit
2. Save JPG95 and JPG83 from Tiff Original
3. Conduct further resave operations as specified
4. Load comparison images and use SSIM Index Plugin

NOTE: many people looking at SSIM values for the first time read them as percentages and assume the difference is small. This is not necessarily true. SSIM values should be compared relative to one another rather than considered as a variance from 1.

Comment: @xiota, I'm using an SSIM plugin for ImageJ. It is one of few SSIM implementations that allows adjustment to parameters (I set the filter width to be 8 so that it would be more likely to detect changes within the 16px JPEG blocks.) I prefer SSIM because it is more sensitive to differences in energy redistribution. A difference image can be misleading if differences cancel out or the differences are concentrated in a small area.

Comment: And to your second question, that says that the difference going from JPG95 to JPG83 to JPG95 is the same as going from Tiff to JPG83. If you want Tiff-JPG95-JPG83-JPG95, that is .9923

Comment: Added a try with four different compressions. The loss is still greater but it's clear that the "convergence" seen over several generations of the same compression is also present when trying multiple different compressions. Still would like to try this in an App-centric workflow but that takes a bit more legwork.

Comment: Another issue is that there isn't a standard mapping of "quality" settings to SSIM thresholds, nor is there any way to determine what quality setting would be needed to avoid significant loss of information.  If one loads a JPEG and saves it at a high enough setting, additional quality loss may be avoided but the file will likely get bigger.  If one doesn't know what setting was used when a file was produced, it may be hard to determine what setting to use when re-saving it.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing like some experimentation. The following bash script (written on Linux, could work on OSX if you have [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)):

- starting with a first image (named `step000.jpg`)
- takes a JPEG file, adds a white dot (to prove this is a new image) and saves it as a (lossless PNG)
- takes the PNG, and re-compresses it as a JPEG (so we never compress JPEG-to-JPEG, and cannot hypothesize that the software just copies encoded blocks)
- makes an image that shows the different pixels between the two JPEGs
- rinse and repeat, using the output JPG of the previous step

The result is that:

1. there isn't much loss at high JPG qualities
2. round-off errors eventually settle, after a short number of generations, things don't degrade any more.

Of course all this assumes that the JPEG is saved by the same software with the same parameters each time.

```
#! /bin/bash
# Runs successive JPEG saves on an image to evaluate JPEG losses

# convert & compare command from imagemagick
# if you use a recent version of IM, set these variables to:
# compare="magick compare"
# convert="magick convert"
convert=convert
compare=compare

dotradius=2
defaultsteps=10
defaultquality=90 # default quality for "convert"

function usage {
        echo "Usage: $0 [quality [steps]]"
        echo ""
        echo "Where:"
        echo "       - 'quality' is the quality factor of the JPEG compression "
        echo "          (1-100, 100 is best, default is $defaultquality)"
        echo "       - 'steps' is the number of successive steps to perform"
        echo "         (default is $defaultsteps)"
        echo ""
        echo "Produces:"
        echo "   - successive saves of a JPEG image to test JPEG-induced losses."
        echo "   - compare images with the original file and the 1st JPEG save."
        echo ""
        echo "Starts from a 'step000.jpg' file in the current directory."
        exit 1
}

[[ -n "$3" ]] && { usage ; exit 1 ; }
steps=${1:-$defaultsteps}
quality=${2:-$defaultquality}    
dotcolor="white" # change this if the top of the image is too clear

echo "Running with $steps steps with quality $quality"

for step in $(seq $steps)
do 
    echo "Step $step of $steps"
    src=$(printf step%03d $(( $step - 1 )) ) 
    dst=$(printf step%03d $(( $step )) )
    dif=$(printf diff%03d $(( $step )) )
    # dot coordinates
    let cxc="2 * $dotradius * $step"
    let cxr="$cxc + $dotradius"
    let cyc="$dotradius * 2"
    let cyr="$dotsradius * 2"

    $convert $src.jpg -fill white -draw "circle $cxc,$cyc,$cxr,$cyr" $dst.png
    $convert $dst.png -quality $quality $dst.jpg
    rm $dst.png
    $compare $src.jpg $dst.jpg $dif.jpg
done
```

For the time being I won't show the results, I prefer to let you experiment with your own pictures. With enough comments, I'll add a sample.

Comment: I was curious about the different software thing. I tried saving 7x from 7 different software. The difference was quite large so I broke it down to see if each application had the same loss. 1 of the apps was responsible for all of the variation. Once I removed the red herring, 6x saves from 6x programs was the same as 6x saves from ImageJ

Comment: There is likely some badly coded software. It is also possible that mixing the algorithms from various apps will prevent the round-off errors from settling, too.

Comment: @xiota, it was an odd little program called FLEMinimizer. I don't even remember why I had it in the first place. The others were ImageJ, Matlab, Photoshop, FastStone Image Viewer, Ifranview, and CameraRaw. There was almost no variation at any step between those six.